# Debug deployed sharepoint triggers

Tags: debugging, sharepoint, triggers, sharepoint-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I have a set of event receivers on SharePoint for when a discussion is Added or Updated however I can't find a way to debug them in Visual Studio once they're deployed. Is there a process I can attach, if so how would I find that process?

Comment: http://sharepoint-kings.blogspot.com/2013/02/debugging-event-receivers-in-sharepoint.html

Answer (score 0):

In SP2010, you can configure event receivers to Synchronous or Asynchronous.

By default event receivers are asynchronous meaning that they run under the SharePoint timer service (OWSTIMER.exe), you can attach to OWSTIMER.EXE and wait till they are executed.

If you set it to Synchronous, then the event receivers run immediately and under the w3wp.exe process, you can attach to w3wp.exe process.